# To serialize or to keep a separate table?

Tags: php, mysql

This question has risen on many different occasions for me but it's hard to explain without giving a specific example. So here goes:

Let's imagine for a while that we are creating a issue tracker database in PHP/MySQL. There is a "tasks" table. Now you need to keep track of people who are associated with a particular task (have commented or what not). These persons will get an email when a task changes.

There are two ways to solve this type of situation. One is to create a separate table tasks_participants:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task_participants` (
  `task_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `task_id_person_id` (`task_id`,`person_id`)
);
```

And to query this table with `SELECT person_id WHERE task_id='XXX'`.

If there are 5000 tasks and each task has 4 participants in average (the reporter, the subject for whom the task brought benefit, the solver and one commenter) then the task_participants table would be 5000*4 = 20 000 rows.

There is also another way: create a field in tasks table and store serialized array (JSON or PHP serialize()) of person_id's. Then there would not be need for this 20 000 rows table.

What are your comments, which way would you go?

Answer (score 6):

Go with the multiple records. It promotes database normalization. Normalization is very important. Updating a serialized value is no fun to maintain. With multiple records I can let the database do the work with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. Also, you are limiting your future joins by having a multivalued column.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I'd give :) @OP : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization is worth a read for further details, too.

Comment: Also look at how someone's role should be modeled.  I'm guessing that the "assigned to" participant should be directly referenced in the task table.  I would also have a comment table containing a reference to an author.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do the cross reference table (the first option you listed).  Why?

- **First of all, do not worry about the size of the cross reference table.**  Relational databases would have been out on their ear decades ago if they could not handle the scale of a simple cross reference table.  Stop worrying about 20K or 200K records, etc.  In fact, if you're going to worry about something like this, it's better to start worrying about why you've chosen a relational DB instead of a key-value DB.  After that, and only when it actually starts to be a problem, then you can start worrying about adding an index or other tuning techniques.
- **Second, if you serialize the association info, you're *probably* opaque-ifying a whole dimension of your data that only your specialized JSON-enabled app can query.**  Serialization of data into a single cell in a table typically only makes sense if the embedded structure is (a) not something that contains data you would never need to query outside your app, (b) is not something you need to query the internals of efficiently (e.g., avg count(*) of people with tasks), and (c) is just something you either do not have time to model out properly or is in a prototypical state.  So I say *probably* above, because it's not usually the case that data worth persisting fits these criteria.
- **Finally, by serializing your data, you are now forced to solve any computation on that serialized data in your code, which is just a big waste of time that you could have spent doing something more productive.**  Your database already can slice and dice that data any way you need, yet because your data is not in a format it understands, you need to now do that in your code.  And now imagine what happens when you change the serialized data structure in V2.

I won't say there aren't use cases for serializing data (I've done it myself), but based on your case above, this probably isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of great answers already, but they explain things in rather theoretical terms.  Here's my (essentially identical) answer, in plain English:

1) 20k records is *nothing* to MySQL.  If it gets up into the 20 million record range, then you might want to start getting concerned - but it still probably won't be an issue.

2) OK, let's assume you've gone with concatenating all the people involved with a ticket into a single field.  Now...  Quick!  Tell me how many tickets Alice has touched!  I have a feeling that Bob is screwing things up and Charlie is covering for him - can you get me a list of tickets that they both worked on, divided up by who touched them last?

With a separate table, MySQL itself can find answers to all kinds of questions about who worked on what tickets and it can find them *fast*.  With everything crammed into a single field, you pretty much have to resort to using `LIKE` queries to find the (potentially) relevant records, then post-process the query results to extract the important data and summarize it yourself.